# How does one update state in a React application after an axios get request tied to an event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

By submitting a form in this React project I want to make an axios get request to the google places API, but I can't get my state to update. It doesn't seem that componentDidMount() can be tied to an event like my handleSubmit(). Any suggestions on updating my state?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Search from "../Components/Search";
import ResultContainer from "../Components/ResultContainer";

export default class Body extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      city: "",
      sights: {},
      bites: {}
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ city: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);

    axios
      .get(
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json? 
         query=attractions+in+" +
          this.state.city +
          "&key=myKeyFromGoogle",
        {
          mode: "no-cors",
          header: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Orgin": "http://localhost:3000",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
              "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
          },
          withCredentials: true,
          credentials: "same-origin"
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ sights: response.data.results });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search
          city={this.state.city}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />

        <ResultContainer sights= {this.state.sights}/>
        <ResultContainer />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to setState after the axios request it doesn't seem that I have the data ready to render. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think "response.data.results" is array of objects. If it is then in you constructor change sights: [];

Comment: console.log response before setState.

Comment: And also you can use componentWillReceiveProps() life cycle to update the sights.

Comment: Move your requests to controller such as thunk or saga.

Comment: Try using arrow function.

Comment: @null when i try arrow functions it then says my method is undefined. Would be a HUGE help if you could please show me how to handle that...

Answer (score 0):

In handleSubmit() function use the concept of conext.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  var _this = this;
  //then use in setState as bellow
  _this.setState({ sights: response.data.results});
}
```

Comment: Tried this. I'm able to console.log(_this) after setState but still catching an error. Any thoughts?